# Dismiss popover using UIbutton

Tags: iphone, ipad

I can't figure out why it doesn't work as it should when I try to dismiss a popover by clicking on a UIButton which itself is on a the popover to be dismissed, my project crashes...

```
- (IBAction) cancelButton: (id) sender{
//[self dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Above is my code for my UIButton

Comment: What's the crash message (look in the console)?

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
(gdb)

Comment: Is your callback specified as @selector(cancelButton) with the missing colon?

Answer (score 19):

Dont dismiss the popover from within its self. Make a protocol that sends a message to its delegate to then dismiss it. For example, your popover view controller might look like this..

```
// MyPopoverViewController.h

@protocol MyPopoverDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)didClickCancelButton;
@end

@interface MyPopoverViewController : UIViewController {

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyPopoverDelegate> delegate; 

-(IBAction)cancelButton;

@end

// MyPopoverViewController.m
#import "MyPopoverViewController.h"

@implementation MyPopoverViewController

@synthesize delegate;

 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

-(IBAction)cancelButton {
   [self.delegate didClickCancelButton];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Rotation support

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory Management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {   
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

And then you could use..

```
//  ClassImplementingPopoverController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyPopoverViewController.h"

@interface ClassImplementingPopoverController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate, MyPopoverDelegate> {

    UIPopoverController *myPopoverController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *myPopoverController;

@end

//  ClassImplementingPopoverController.m

#import "ClassImplementingPopoverController.h"
#import "MyPopoverViewController.h"


@implementation ClassImplementingPopoverController

@synthesize myPopoverController;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations.
     return YES;
 }

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark MyPopover delegate

-(void)didClickCancelButton {
    if ([myPopoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
       [myPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
       [myPopoverController release];
    }
 }

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIPopoverController delegate

-(void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    if (popoverController == myPopoverController) {
        [myPopoverController release];
    }
}

/* Use something like this to create your popover, just make sure you set the delegate to self so you can receive the messages 

        NSLog(@"Displaying Popover!");
        MyPopoverViewController *detailViewController = [[MyPopoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyPopoverViewController" bundle:nil];
        [detailViewController setDelegate:self];
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.     
        myPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:detailViewController];
        [detailViewController release];
        myPopoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(500.0, 150.0);
        [myPopoverController setDelegate:self];
*/

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.myPopoverController = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [myPopoverController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: hai ur ans is right it working very nice thank’s @Renegade428

Comment: your delegate method not working..any suggestion i am working with xcode 4.3.3

Answer (score 3):

you can use KVC accessing "popoverController" like

```
[self valueForKey:@"popoverController"]
```

But it is potentially rejected by AppStore if they detect your code is using their's "private API".

Answer (score 0):

dismissPopoverAnimated is a property on the PopoverController itself, not your custom VC.  You are showing an IBAction on 'self', which suggests you are inside your own class here.  (Please post more surrounding code if that isn't correct.)

A VC can't get to its enclosing popover directly; you just need to keep a reference to it in the VC that created it so you can hit it with dismiss from there.

You can dismiss a Popover from inside itself, that doesn't crash.