# IPhone App: Dismiss PopView On Button Click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uipopovercontroller

In my iPhone App As shown below I have implemented PopViewController

Now on Button Click (Dismiss) I want to dismiss the pop view

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is

```
if ([PopViewController isPopoverVisible]) {
     [PopViewController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

nevertheless, assuming you are using an external button there are many delegate issues that can play a part in this problem I suggest you refer to this post : [Dismiss popover using UIbutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565968/dismiss-popover-using-uibutton/5008670#5008670)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
     [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
  }
```

add somting like `@class ViewCntrollerClass2;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

in .h

```
@protocol popOverDismissDelgate
-(void)dismissPopOverView;
@end

@interface ///
@property(nonatomic,assign) <popOverDismissDelgate> delegate;
@end
```

in .m

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

and write

```
-(void)dismissPopOverView{

 [PopViewController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

}
```

when you creating second view controller to make popover view controller, set delegate to self like

```
SecondView *sv=[[SecondView alloc]initWithNibName:];
sv.delegate=self;
```

in second view controller implement this method

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped{
[(id)delegate performSelector:@selector(dismissPopOverView)];
}
```

Tis will dismiss your popover view