# Dismiss popover on UIButton click is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.3, uipopovercontroller, popover

I am attempting to dismiss a popover as well as return a variable when a button is clicked in the popover. There are four buttons and on selection of a button, the variable (based on the button) will be returned to the original view controller and the popover will close. I am unsure of how to attempt the passing of the variable, but I am attempting to at least do the popover close on button click using this page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565968/dismiss-popover-using-uibutton), which for some reason doesn't work for me. When I click on the button absolutely nothing happens.

AddWineViewController is the "root" view controller

```
//AddWineViewController.h
//this is the "root" view controller
#import "WineStyleViewController.h"
@interface AddWineViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate, MyPopoverDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *myPopoverController;
```

```
//AddWineViewController.m
@implementation AddWineViewController
@synthesize myPopoverController;
-(void)didClickCancelButton {
    //I would like to have the variable passed here, something like self.wineStyle.text=wineStyle; where wineStyle is the variable from the popover.
    [myPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

WineStyleViewController is the popover view controller

```
//WineStyleViewController.h
@protocol MyPopoverDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void)didClickCancelButton;
@end
@interface WineStyleViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyPopoverDelegate> delegate; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *wineStyle;
- (IBAction)redWineButton:(id)sender;
```

```
//WineStyleViewController.m
@implementation WineStyleViewController
@synthesize wineStyle;
@synthesize delegate;

- (IBAction)redWineButton:(id)sender {
    wineStyle=@"Red";
    [self.delegate didClickCancelButton];
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that sets up the `WineStyleViewController` and makes an instance of `AddWineViewController` its delegate. Doesn't this create a retain cycle?.. You may need to make your delegate `__weak`, although it is certainly not a cause of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make a few assumptions first, being that all of your connections in your storyboard are connected, and all objects are properly created, and that you have set delegate to self in your segue.

Just to be certain ... make sure your segue includes:

```
// set your destination view controller
WineStyleViewController *destinationController = segue.destinationViewController;
destinationController.delegate=self;
```

In your delegate (popover): WineStyleViewController, you define your protocol as:

```
@protocol MyPopoverDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void)didClickCancelButton;
@end
```

but you want to pass back the wineStyle to the root controller (AddWineViewController) so you need to 
1) add the variable (wineStyle) to pass back and 2) pass along your delegate's ViewController (I took the liberty to change to Save instead of cancel)

```
@protocol MyPopoverDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)didClickSaveButton (WineStyleViewController *)wineStyleViewController withWineStyle (NSString *)wineStyle;
@end
```

Now going back to AddWineViewController:

your `-(void)didClickCancelButton:(WineStyle)wineStyle` is where you will receive from your delegate your wine style, so this method should look more like: (again changing it save)

```
-(void)didSave
{
    // your methods for dealing with your added wineStyle go hear, as
    // you will already have wineStyle sent back to you from your delegate
    [myPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

hope that helps :D

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have correctly made the IBAction connection (and the method is actually executing when you press the button); so then my next thought is that the `self.delegate` is not being set properly as the controller is coming on-screen (in the `AddWineViewController`'s method where the popover is presented).

Additionally, I should mention that I would probably change the interface of the protocol a little bit with a few things in mind:

1. I would not tell the delegate that cancel was pressed to trigger the dismissal of the popover; tell it instead that a selection has been made.
2. I prefer protocol methods which pass the "child" along in the signature: `[self.delegate didChooseWineStyle: self]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was using an example online which is why I chose "cancel" as the button text but that isn't what I will keep in the long run. The actions were set up properly. The code you suggested `[self.delegate didChooseWineStyle:self]` leads to an error: `No known instance method for selector 'didClickCancelButton'`

Comment: You'll need to write that method (and perhaps put it in the public interface for the delegate via `@protocol`)  in the delegate's class.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got this figured out but I ended up using a picker instead of a table. I'm slowly getting the hang of this!

Answer (score 1):

To pass "wineStyle" to your "MyPopover" protocol, simply add the variable to the protocol:

```
@protocol MyPopoverDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void)didClickCancelButton:(WineStyle)wineStyle;
@end
```

..and make sure its sent to the delegate, like this:

```
if ([delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyPopoverDelegate)]) {
   if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didClickCancelButton:)]) {
       [delegate didClickCancelButton:selectedWineStyle];
   }
}
```

Regarding the Popover not being dismissed, make sure that you store a reference to the UIPopoverController and simply call:

```
- (void)didClickCancelButton:(WineStyle)wineStyle {
   // ... do something with "wineStyle" here
   [currentPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment, but unfortunately `-(void)didClickCancelButton` is not ever being called properly when I hit the button on my popover. Hence my problem in the first place. I think once I can get the `didClickCancelButton` to call, then passing the variable will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the popover controller what popover to possess, you aren't doing that. I'm not sure how you're presenting your view, but you should have something like

```
   UIPopoverController paparazzi = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:temp];
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment but I don't know where this line of code belongs.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial really helped me out with a similar issue:
http://ios.biomsoft.com/2011/10/17/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2/

Comment: Thanks for the comment but that tutorial has nothing to do with popover views.

Comment: It may not be a "popover" but pay attention to the segue/delegate portion and how to pass information back and forth.