# iOS: Storyboard Segue loads before class method call

Tags: ios, xcode

I have two scenes. A regular, full-screen iPad view and another popover view. Tapping a button loads the popover view with no problems. In the popover view I have a button that will perform some action and is also linked to a storyboard modal transition.

The idea is that pressing the button from the popover view will save the user's selection state and send that data to the main view. I have no issues with the data saving, that works just fine.

The issue I am having is that when I press the button from the popover view, the main view's `viewDidLoad` method actually completes before the popover view's `IBAction` method does. So the main view gets the data, but since the view already loaded it is not able to update the label in time.

I tried creating multiple popover view scenes and added multiple buttons to the main view that will link to these new scenes. The weird part is that some of them work just fine. Some of them will perform the `IBAction` method and then it transitions back to the main view via a modal transition. There seems to be no rhyme or reason why one loads before the other.

I suppose a possible solution would be to perform the transition manually within the `IBAction` method of the popover view. I am definitely new to this so there may be something fundamental about transitions that I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view controller of view on which the button is present... When segue is going to be performed. You can pass data in

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
}
```

This method is called before the view is loaded..

Comment: Yeah that's what I will end up doing. I was just curious as to what the method call priority was and why the behavior seemed erratic.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling a popover so the main screen should not call viewDidLoad method because the main view still on the back. It should be calling the viewWillAppear and the viewDidApper methods instead.

Can you check this? I think you should refresh the main screen after one of these two methods are called.

Give it a try and tell me the results.

Comment: I threw in a few NSLogs and it appears that viewDidLoad is still called when I press the buttons. They are set up as a modal transition though.

Comment: Alright I placed those methods in the main `UIViewController` and added NSLogs to each of them. They both execute BEFORE the method in my popover executes. Thus, the view finishes loading before the `IBAction` method is processed even though the user clicks on the button BEFORE the popover is closed.

Comment: Ok, but I'm not sure about this sequence. How did your popover is called if the main view is not yet completely loaded? Did you force the open of the first popover? If so you should try open it in the viewDidAppear method.

Comment: I am coming from the perspective of the main scene is already loaded. I click on the popover with no issues. When I leave the popover the main `viewDidLoad` method is called before the popover's `IBAction` method AS the popover is closing back to the main view.

Comment: Ok, witch button did you press on the popover? It's the back button of a navigationbar?

Comment: I have created a new `UIButton` on the popover. The action simply changes the value of a boolean. The same button is also connected to the main `UIViewController` via a segue in storyboard.

Comment: Ok I think that I got it. Check if the other button's also have this connection to the mainviewcontroller via segue. I think you need to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565968/dismiss-popover-using-uibutton/5008670#5008670